# app engine - how can i increase the datastore item size limit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

how can i increase the datastore item size limit, which is now only 1 MB, in app engine?
if i buy more storage what will happen to this limit?
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly. Enabling billing won't remove the 1MB entity size limit, however it will allow you to use the Blobstore API, where you can store blobs up to 2GB in size. These are typically uploaded files, but could just as easily be pickled python objects.

While each entity is limited to 1MB, HTTP requests and responses can be up to 10MB, so you can handle slightly larger files by spanning the blob contents across multiple entities, splitting the file on upload and stitching it back together on download.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Blobstore API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) to handles objects that are larger than 1 Mb.

Answer (score -3):

I dont know what limit 1MB you exactly talking about but for GAE if you want to do anything above the [free quota](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Billable_Quotas_and_Fixed_Quotas), [enable billing](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html#Enabling_Billing) for your application :)

Comment: Max entity size is 1mb.

 http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits